# Black Screen on AnyDesk Connection while using RDP

Tags: remote-desktop

I want to use AnyDesk to navigate on my server rather than RDP. When I connect to it via AnyDesk, it only shows a black screen and nothing else. When I connect to RDP while keeping the AnyDesk connection the screen magically appears on AnyDesk! However, when I disconnect from RDP, the screen on AnyDesk freezes and I can't do anything besides reconnecting just to see the black screen again. Is there any way to keep the AnyDesk connection without having to be connected to RDP?